# postfix - TLS/SSL error when receiving emails

Tags: ssl, postfix, tls

I can receive emails from gmail, however certain other servers are getting rejected when they try to send emails to my server

Here are the logs when I tried to get authentication from *startcom.org* as well as some other server attempting to send me something the day before.

```
Oct 11 05:26:54 snw postfix/smtpd[2342]: connect from 118-161-77-187.dynamic.hinet.net[118.161.77.187]
Oct 11 05:26:55 snw postfix/smtpd[2342]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from 118-161-77-187.dynamic.hinet.net[118.161.77.187]: 454 4.7.1 <support@microsoft.com>: Relay access denied; from=<support@microsoft.com> to=<support@microsoft.com> proto=SMTP helo=<159.8.48.206>
Oct 11 05:26:56 snw postfix/smtpd[2342]: lost connection after RCPT from 118-161-77-187.dynamic.hinet.net[118.161.77.187]
Oct 11 05:26:56 snw postfix/smtpd[2342]: disconnect from 118-161-77-187.dynamic.hinet.net[118.161.77.187]
Oct 11 05:30:16 snw postfix/anvil[2344]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:118.161.77.187) at Oct 11 05:26:54
Oct 11 05:30:16 snw postfix/anvil[2344]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:118.161.77.187) at Oct 11 05:26:54
Oct 11 05:30:16 snw postfix/anvil[2344]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Oct 11 05:26:54
Oct 11 12:31:05 snw postfix/smtpd[2613]: connect from 118-161-77-187.dynamic.hinet.net[118.161.77.187]
Oct 11 12:31:06 snw postfix/smtpd[2613]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from 118-161-77-187.dynamic.hinet.net[118.161.77.187]: 454 4.7.1 <support@microsoft.com>: Relay access denied; from=<support@microsoft.com> to=<support@microsoft.com> proto=SMTP helo=<159.8.48.206>
Oct 11 12:31:07 snw postfix/smtpd[2613]: lost connection after RCPT from 118-161-77-187.dynamic.hinet.net[118.161.77.187]
Oct 11 12:31:07 snw postfix/smtpd[2613]: disconnect from 118-161-77-187.dynamic.hinet.net[118.161.77.187]
Oct 11 12:34:27 snw postfix/anvil[2615]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:118.161.77.187) at Oct 11 12:31:05
Oct 11 12:34:27 snw postfix/anvil[2615]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:118.161.77.187) at Oct 11 12:31:05
Oct 11 12:34:27 snw postfix/anvil[2615]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Oct 11 12:31:05
Oct 11 13:45:07 snw dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 1 secs): user=<>, rip=141.212.122.112, lip=159.8.48.206, TLS: Disconnected, session=<pGIDxtch6QCN1Hpw>
Oct 11 23:42:31 snw postfix/smtpd[3020]: connect from 118-161-77-187.dynamic.hinet.net[118.161.77.187]
Oct 11 23:42:32 snw postfix/smtpd[3020]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from 118-161-77-187.dynamic.hinet.net[118.161.77.187]: 454 4.7.1 <support@microsoft.com>: Relay access denied; from=<support@microsoft.com> to=<support@microsoft.com> proto=SMTP helo=<159.8.48.206>
Oct 11 23:42:33 snw postfix/smtpd[3020]: lost connection after RCPT from 118-161-77-187.dynamic.hinet.net[118.161.77.187]
Oct 11 23:42:33 snw postfix/smtpd[3020]: disconnect from 118-161-77-187.dynamic.hinet.net[118.161.77.187]
Oct 11 23:45:53 snw postfix/anvil[3022]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:118.161.77.187) at Oct 11 23:42:31
Oct 11 23:45:53 snw postfix/anvil[3022]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:118.161.77.187) at Oct 11 23:42:31
Oct 11 23:45:53 snw postfix/anvil[3022]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Oct 11 23:42:31
Oct 12 17:28:53 snw postfix/smtpd[3682]: connect from gateway.startcom.org[212.117.158.94]
Oct 12 17:28:55 snw postfix/smtpd[3682]: 12EE9DA2954: client=gateway.startcom.org[212.117.158.94]
Oct 12 17:28:55 snw postfix/smtpd[3682]: lost connection after RCPT from gateway.startcom.org[212.117.158.94]
Oct 12 17:28:55 snw postfix/smtpd[3682]: disconnect from gateway.startcom.org[212.117.158.94]
Oct 12 17:29:01 snw postfix/smtpd[3682]: connect from apache-7.startcom.org[192.116.242.7]
Oct 12 17:29:01 snw postfix/smtpd[3682]: SSL_accept error from apache-7.startcom.org[192.116.242.7]: -1
Oct 12 17:29:01 snw postfix/smtpd[3682]: warning: TLS library problem: 3682:error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_srvr.c:647:
Oct 12 17:29:01 snw postfix/smtpd[3682]: lost connection after STARTTLS from apache-7.startcom.org[192.116.242.7]
Oct 12 17:29:01 snw postfix/smtpd[3682]: disconnect from apache-7.startcom.org[192.116.242.7]
```

Here are the logs when I use gmail to send to my sever

```
Oct 12 17:58:05 snw postfix/smtpd[3968]: connect from mail-io0-f174.google.com[209.85.223.174]
Oct 12 17:58:05 snw postfix/smtpd[3968]: E3E54DA0A51: client=mail-io0-f174.google.com[209.85.223.174]
Oct 12 17:58:06 snw postfix/cleanup[3977]: E3E54DA0A51: message-id=<CADZik+Vnys--dh_dhOqTSE2ZePWZiBKVp9-EqnYAyJRfk+hQGA@mail.gmail.com>
Oct 12 17:58:06 snw postfix/qmgr[5644]: E3E54DA0A51: from=<bnguyen170@gmail.com>, size=1931, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct 12 17:58:06 snw postfix/smtpd[3968]: disconnect from mail-io0-f174.google.com[209.85.223.174]
Oct 12 17:58:06 snw postfix/pipe[3980]: E3E54DA0A51: to=<admin@phantastyc.tk>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.77, delays=0.38/0.1/0/0.29, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
Oct 12 17:58:06 snw postfix/qmgr[5644]: E3E54DA0A51: removed
```

I use:

- Roundcube as an IMAP client (probably irrelevant)
- Dovecot for auth with virtual users on MySQL
- Postfix as mail software (`postconf` output [here](https://gist.github.com/bnguyen654/111f88b42379e47393e3#file-main-cf))

I suspect this has something to do with my server being restrictive on SSL/TLS auth, but how do I configure my server so that it will accept almost anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is evident in these log lines:

```
Oct 12 17:29:01 snw postfix/smtpd[3682]: SSL_accept error from apache-7.startcom.org[192.116.242.7]: -1
Oct 12 17:29:01 snw postfix/smtpd[3682]: warning: TLS library problem: 3682:error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_srvr.c:647:
```

apache7-startcom.org tries to set up an SSL/TLS connection but fails, probably because it tries to speak an SSL/TLS protocol your server doesn't accept.

You should really post the output of just `postconf -n` so it shows only the configuration parameters that are different from the defaults. Your `postconf` output contains too much noise to be really useful.

That said in [line 713](https://gist.github.com/bnguyen654/111f88b42379e47393e3#file-main-cf-L713) of your `postconf` gist you seem to forbid every TLS protocol except TLSv1.2. This is very restrictive and probably too much for a mail server that should be able to accept incoming mail. I would set the relevant TLS configuration parameters like this:

```
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
```

That way you disable SSLv2 and SSLv3, both of which are broken and insecure, and leave TLSv1, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 available. Restart Postfix after adding or changing these parameters in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same situation with connecting gmail to my postfix server, and the same error message.  Turned out that permissions and SELinux context on my certificate & key were incorrect.

In my case, I did an sftp put to get the certs onto the server, then I had copied the entire directory including the certificates to the final location.

```
restorecon -rv [directory]
```

to restore the correct SELinux context, if you moved the directory from somewhere else (or with the -Z flag).

Make sure that when you correct the permission and ownership (root:root & 640), that you do it to the entire directory, recursively, not just the files inside the directory.

/etc/postfix/main.cfg  (just the relevant part)

```
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes

#Do not forget that the directory and contents have to be owned by root
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com-0001/fullchain7.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com-0001/privkey7.pem
```